# Ошибка ограничений обобщений C#

Tags: c#, .net

```
class NameClass<T> : ParentClass, INameClass<T> where T : List<A>, List<B>, new() {}
```

Создаю класс, где `<T>` булет принимать значения `List<A>` или `List<B>`.

У меня ругается на `List<B>`.

Говорит:

*Ошибка CS0406 Все другие ограничения должны следовать после ограничения типа класса "`List<B>`"*

Если меняю местами регается на `List<A>`.

**EDIT:**

```
class NameClass<T> : ParentClass, INameClass<T> where T : List<T>, new() {}
```

Если написать так, то ошибки нет. Но я не уверен будет ли это правильно работать, не будет ли закольцованности?

Comment: *Создаю класс, где `<T>` булет принимать значения `List<A>` или `List<B>`* — но то что вы объявили означает, что T будет одновременно **и `List<A>` и `List<B>`**

Comment: @АндрейNOP А как тогда сделать правильно и то, что мне надо?

Comment: Если же у вас такое условие на List, почему бы вам тогда просто T не посылать в класс, а уже внутри класса брать IList<T>? Объясните, что вы хотите сделать, может быть станет понятнее...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибка CS0406 возникает, потому что ты пытаешься определить параметр `Т` как наследник от двух классов, что невозможно в C#.

В целом, как уже было отмечено в комментариях, по вопросу очень сложно судить о желаемом результате определения класса. Но, попытавшись догадаться, предлагаю такой вариант:

```
class NameClass<T> : ParentClass, INameClass<T> where T : List<ICommonAB>, new() {}
```

где `ParentClass`, `INameClass<T>`, `ICommonAB` - уже определённые ранее классы, а также `ICommonAB` является общим предком (или интерфейсом) классов `A` и `B`.

Comment: Спасибо за совет.